# git failed to read object error

Tags: git, git-svn

Due to heavy power cuts, my computer was getting powered off every now and then. Now when I try ti give a git status command in one of the repositories, I get an error:

```
fatal: failed to read object bbf5a710cc9d8ad557355f43fafb6ec4652370da: Invalid argument
```

I search for this issue, but all my attempts failed. Can anybody help me, as I need to submit this project by this weekend :(

Comment: Try this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8616352/390522

Comment: Do you have a remote repository as well?

Comment: no i did not push it to a remote repo :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it. I just added the remote origin and pushed it ti to a remote repo(bitbucket) and I did a git clone, everything was fine then. :) Thanks for the reply..