# How do i recover my git stash after git stash pop was successful

Tags: git, git-stash

I had changes in a few files and some new files

`git pull`: said I had conflicts in a few files

I did :

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

I expected conflicts but there were none.

Instead many files are now just empty.
current uncommitted changes show everything deleted from these files.

Solution I see is: clone the repository. "somehow recover" my last popped stash and save it as a patch and apply there.

How do I recover this (it is not in the stash list anymore)

I don't see the last stash using :

```
gitk --all $( git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' )
```

and

```
git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}'
```

gives :

```
error: object file .git/objects/02/7745a5151a6237eb1dcd8e4f0df10328809669 is empty
error: object file .git/objects/02/7745a5151a6237eb1dcd8e4f0df10328809669 is empty
fatal: loose object 027745a5151a6237eb1dcd8e4f0df10328809669 (stored in .git/objects/02/7745a5151a6237eb1dcd8e4f0df10328809669) is corrupt
```

What do I do? What happened?

Comment: I don't think this has to do with `git stash`, the fsck indicates your repository is damaged. `git stash pop` didn't do that. Did your computer crash?

Comment: no my computer didn't crash.
although might be disk corruption issue.
what do i do now?

Comment: Now you look into fixing a corrupted repository. Here's one question on the subject. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271263/repair-corrupted-git-repository

Answer (score 3):

I find the official document has a solution.

[Recovering stash entries that were cleared/dropped erroneously](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-Recoveringstashentriesthatwerecleareddroppederroneously)

> If you mistakenly drop or clear stash entries, they cannot be
>   recovered through the normal safety mechanisms. However, you can try
>   the following incantation to get a list of stash entries that are
>   still in your repository, but not reachable any more:

```sh
git fsck --unreachable |
grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 |
xargs git log --merges --no-walk --grep=WIP
```

Answer (score -5):

Have you tried using:

```
git stash list
```

You should have a list of stashes that you've done. Then you can select the one you want to apply:

```
git stash apply stash@{1}
```

Before you apply the stash I imagine you want to have the HEAD on same position before you ran the first git pull.

Comment: Unlike `git stash apply`, if `git stash pop` is successful it removes the entry from the stash. It won't be in the list.

Comment: yes. it was applied successfully. not there anymore