# Git - remove missing blobs or trees

Tags: git, git-fsck

Is there a way to remove references to a missing blob or tree from the history? Here is the output of `git fsck --full`

```
broken link from    tree 99fe1a9d46985ca21e88de53a7a290e2b1889722
              to    blob bf70d7b3bf98852e13dd0b3b8499ad5d77f174d9
broken link from    tree e3dbfdf73cb5c9971b95b33da5fc93f5d69acdae
              to    tree 5d02b92042c23945f41c5a895e5fc7f4d5a4988d
missing blob bf70d7b3bf98852e13dd0b3b8499ad5d77f174d9
missing blob 1d918846d68d8a8368cc442b6d5989d275944c39
dangling blob 42c2d0f36c782a48f793f6c381578e0e5611b602
missing tree 5d02b92042c23945f41c5a895e5fc7f4d5a4988d
missing blob e9d2ae0e7d9c30dec40a116a12a97567e29a87d2
dangling blob 1aa5f9b48ea74f4a75aa848c571f223995c36658
dangling blob 94055e2bdcc4399c5563327ff879864c59c95e40
dangling commit 2b46b23ef705d48c03ed2526cad6548d1608644b
missing blob 5f5e29e93984bdb1a4bc3be2ba7ebaba1e595e75
```

My guess is that either a `pull`,`push`, or `git move` got interrupted. I worked out which files most of the missing blobs referred too, but I cannot recover them since they have been since modified and I have no way of reconstructing the changes (I think; but I'm new to git).

`gc`, `prune`, and `reflog --expire=now` did not help.

Is there a way to tell `git` "It's OK buddy, I'm fine with the current state of the current `HEAD`"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interrupting Git will not do this.  Having your system *crash* (reboot) while in the middle of some update might do this, but an ordinary interrupt would not.  Disk failure would also do this.

See [Repair corrupted git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271263/repair-corrupted-git-repository) and [How to fix corrupted git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678853/how-to-fix-corrupted-git-repository) I would just mark this as a duplicate but I'm not sure which of these is a better question-and-answer (though I lean a bit towards the second one myself).

Comment: seems fair. I feel like the second one describes my situation more accurately. Feel free to mark as duplicate.

Comment: Follow-upquestion:  When I try to revert to a commit that might be uncorrupted, I get the following message: `error: unable to read sha1 file of LWS/code/lis_training_2.R (e9d2ae0e7d9c30dec40a116a12a97567e29a87d2) ... fatal: Could not reset index file to revision '7b9ae3ce'`. I do have the missing objects in a remote backup .git folder, but the hashes I get from `git --hash-object -w` differ from the ones I get in the error message. Any advice?

Comment: What are you feeding to `git hash-object -w`? Normally if you have a good backup of a missing or corrupt object you can and should simply copy it into place in `.git/objects/` (using the original path name, e.g., object abcde... becomes ab/cde...).

Comment: If I take the example above, I have `LWS/code/list_training_2.R` in my backup, but I do not have an object `d2ae...` in the backup `.git/objects/e9`. I have two files in the backup `.git/objects/`, an `.idx` and a `.pack`. I'm guessing I need to unpack the latter? This exceeds my git skils and the documentation is not making a lot of sense to me right now.

Comment: Yes, you could unpack the pack file (`git unpack-objects`), but for missing objects, you could also just copy the pack and index files into place: that makes every object in that pack available. (Of course without unpacking it you can't *see* what objects *are* in that pack, at least not directly.) Or, for missing blob or commit objects that you have in the backup pack, you can extract a text form of them with `git cat-file -p` and then use `git hash-object -w` to install them in the other repository. That does not work for tree objects though.

Comment: That did it. Great, thanks. For future reference: I unpacked the `pack` file into a subdirectory of my working directory (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972031/how-to-unpack-all-objects-of-a-git-repository) if, like me, you don't understand the `git unpack-objects` doc). I then manually copied over the missing blobs into the appropriate `.git/objects/...` folder. The hint that object `abcde` is in `ab/cde...` was crucial.